Wilkinson Shift making QR iterations not converge?
I am trying to get eigenvalues and eigenvectors using the QR iterations method.
I noticed my QR method was struggling a bit so I read about the Wilkinson shift which is described at:
$$ \mu = t_{n,n} + d − \mathrm{sign}(d)  \sqrt{d^2 + t^2_{n,n-1}} $$
Where $d$ is the determinant of the bottom right 2x2 submatrix of the current matrix in the QR method, and $t_{i,i}$ are the respective entries of the same matrix.
The shifted qr iterations pseudocode is something like:
loop 
    Q, R = factorize(A - mu I)
    A = R * Q + mu I
    U = U * Q

    if A has converged 
       break

However, even though every resource I can find claims this simple modification should be faster than the naive QR, I am finding that it takes a ridiculous number of additional iterations for the method to converge with the shift than without.
This is my current implementation:
pub fn qr_iterations_with_shift_in_place(
    h: &mut Mat<f64>,
    q_res: &mut Mat<f64>,
) {
    fn has_converged(matrix: &Mat<f64>, tolerance: f64) -> bool {
        for i in 1..matrix.nrows() {
            // Start from 1 to avoid checking the first row
            for j in 0..i {
                // Check only elements below the diagonal
                if matrix[(i, j)].abs() > tolerance {
                    return false; // Found an element below the diagonal larger
                                  // than tolerance
                }
            }
        }
        true // All elements below the diagonal are within tolerance
    }

    let id = Mat::<f64>::identity(h.nrows(), h.ncols());
    let mut shift = id.clone();
    *q_res = Mat::identity(h.nrows(), h.ncols());

    loop {
        let alpha = wilkinson_shift_coeff(h);

        shift = alpha * id.clone();
        let qr = (&*h - &shift).qr();
        let q = qr.compute_q();
        let r = qr.compute_r();

        *h = r * q.as_ref() + shift;
        *q_res = &*q_res * q;

        if has_converged(h, 0.000001) {
            break;
        }
    }
}
// page 6:
// https://dspace.mit.edu/bitstream/handle/1721.1/75282/18-335j-fall-2006/contents/lecture-notes/lec16.pdf
fn wilkinson_shift_coeff(mat: &Mat<f64>) -> f64 {
    debug_assert!(mat.ncols() == mat.nrows());
    let n = mat.nrows() - 1;
    let a_n = mat[(n, n)];
    let a_n_minus = mat[(n - 1, n - 1)];
    let b = mat[(n - 1, n)];
    let delta = (a_n_minus - a_n) / 2.;

    let mu =
        a_n - delta.signum() * b * b / (delta.abs() + (delta * delta + b * b).sqrt());

    mu
}
```


I did not read it here, is your test matrix symmetric? The Wilkinson shift is invented for this case, in the unsymmetric case the eigenvalue formula for the lowest 2x2 block might look different. // Your determinant formula is looking strange, is that from the wiki page?

The determinant computation is correct for a symmetric matrix. Note that the algorithm converges in this case due to the matrix being diagonizable via conjugation with an orthogonal matrix. In the general case, especially if the smallest eigenvalues are a complex-conjugated pair, the sub-diagonal need not converge to zero, in the best case it will be block-diagonal with 2x2 diagonal blocks. These blocks will also not become stationary, only their trace and determinant will. So you need more involved finishing criteria, apart from replacing b*b with b2=mat[(n - 1, n)]*mat[(n, n - 1)].

@LutzLehmann I am working with symmetri matrices atm.
